# Error while extracting sub-pipeline using index from sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pipeline

I've a machine learning pipeline  --

```py
logreg = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))),
                   ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True, use_idf=True)),
                   ('clf', LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1, C=1e2, multi_class='ovr', 
                                              solver='lbfgs', max_iter=1000))])

logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I want to extract the feature matrix from the first two steps of the pipeline. Therefore, I tried to extract the sub-pipeline with first two steps in original pipeline. The following code gives error:

```
logreg[:-1].fit(X)
```

> TypeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

How do I extract the first two steps of the `Pipeline` without building a new pipeline for data transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to execute only part of the steps you can create Pipeline in runtime.

```
partial_pipe = Pipeline(logreg.steps[:-1])
partial_pipe.fit(data)
```

The steps of piple will be available in `steps` variable of Pipeline object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having the old version of sklearn. With the versions `>=0.21.3`, the indexing of pipeline using the way you did, should be possible.

You can see the release notes [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.21.html#sklearn-pipeline)

Example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

categories = ['alt.atheism', 'talk.religion.misc']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                                      categories=categories)

X, y = newsgroups_train.data, newsgroups_train.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y)


logreg = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1))),
                   ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True, use_idf=True)),
                   ('clf', LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1, C=1e2,
                                              multi_class='ovr',
                                              solver='lbfgs', max_iter=1000))])
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
logreg[:-1].fit_transform(X_train)

# <599x15479 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#   with 107539 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```